# Alternative to browser for viewing Jupyter notebooks on iOS

Tags: ios, python

I use Jupyter notebooks a lot when working on physics lab reports, and I'd like to be able to work on them on my iPad more than on my home computer. [I know that I can just start the notebook server on my computer and access it from the web browser on my iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440263/is-there-a-way-to-access-python-2-7-jupyter-notebook-on-my-linux-desktop-from-my), and I've used the [Computable app in the past](http://computableapp.com/blog/), but I was wondering if there was a still-maintained (native) app for viewing, editing and running Jupyter notebooks on iOS.

Comment: So, basically, you're looking for an IOS app to view Jupyter notebooks? What is lacking (besides the maintenance) of the Computable app?

Comment: @Tom  I can't download it from the App Store or from local iTunes backups onto my iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Juno app does most of what I want: you can open notebooks and edit them, either from public or private servers.